# How to net off amount column with same value and different sign from single table using sql server

Tags: sql-server

Below is the dataset. I am trying to net off the value like 59 with -59 and leave with value that is not getting net off.

I tried joining with same table as per below query but didn't get expected output

```
+--------+------------+----------+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| Txn_ID | Price_Type | Price_ID | Country | Center |  Amount  | DR_CR |
+--------+------------+----------+---------+--------+----------+-------+
|      1 |       2225 |   439914 | USA     |   3602 |       59 | Cr    |
|      2 |       2225 |   439584 | USA     |   3602 |   157.53 | Cr    |
|      3 |       2225 |   439292 | USA     |   3602 |       59 | Cr    |
|      4 |       2225 |   439816 | USA     |   3602 |       59 | Cr    |
|      5 |       2225 |   439546 | USA     |   6313 |  -497.25 | Dr    |
|      6 |       2225 |   439949 | USA     |   6313 |  1953.15 | Cr    |
|      7 |       2225 |   439546 | USA     |   3602 |       59 | Cr    |
|      8 |       2225 |   439949 | USA     |   3602 |       25 | Cr    |
|      9 |       1083 |   182221 | USA     |   7851 |      -59 | Dr    |
|     10 |       2225 |   438689 | USA     |   3602 |       59 | Cr    |
|     11 |       2225 |   438689 | USA     |   6313 |  -415.88 | Dr    |
|     12 |       2225 |   438965 | USA     |   3602 |       59 | Cr    |
|     13 |       1083 |   182257 | USA     |   7851 |      -59 | Dr    |
|     14 |       1083 |   182251 | USA     |   7851 |      -59 | Dr    |
|     15 |       2225 |   439844 | USA     |   3602 |       25 | Cr    |
|     16 |       1083 |   182265 | USA     |   7851 | -1978.15 | Dr    |
|     17 |       1083 |   182230 | USA     |   7851 |      -25 | Dr    |
|     18 |       1069 |    23888 | USA     |   7851 |   356.88 | Cr    |
|     19 |       1083 |   182225 | USA     |   7851 |   438.25 | Cr    |
+--------+------------+----------+---------+--------+----------+-------+
```

**Query tried to check if expected rows are getting matched :**

`SELECT T1.,T2. FROM Product T1
INNER JOIN Product T2
ON T1.DR_CR<>T2.DR_CR
AND ABS(T1.Amount)=ABS(T2.Amount)
AND T1.Txn_ID<>T2.Txn_ID`

Please can anyone suggest any way to netoff the amount value?

Expected result as per below:

```
+--------+------------+----------+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| Txn_ID | Price_Type | Price_ID | Country | Center |  Amount  | DR_CR |
+--------+------------+----------+---------+--------+----------+-------+
|      2 |       2225 |   439584 | USA     |   3602 |   157.53 | Cr    |
|      5 |       2225 |   439546 | USA     |   6313 |  -497.25 | Dr    |
|      6 |       2225 |   439949 | USA     |   6313 |  1953.15 | Cr    |
|      7 |       2225 |   439546 | USA     |   3602 |       59 | Cr    |
|     10 |       2225 |   438689 | USA     |   3602 |       59 | Cr    |
|     11 |       2225 |   438689 | USA     |   6313 |  -415.88 | Dr    |
|     12 |       2225 |   438965 | USA     |   3602 |       59 | Cr    |
|     15 |       2225 |   439844 | USA     |   3602 |       25 | Cr    |
|     16 |       1083 |   182265 | USA     |   7851 | -1978.15 | Dr    |
|     18 |       1069 |    23888 | USA     |   7851 |   356.88 | Cr    |
|     19 |       1083 |   182225 | USA     |   7851 |   438.25 | Cr    |
+--------+------------+----------+---------+--------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: What would be the expected result? Could you present one?

Comment: @cdrrr I have added expected result in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer after hitting trail and error method.

Below query has partition and assigned the rank to amount and Dr_cr column wise. Then I got required output by joining table with itself.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    select Txn_ID
            ,Price_Type
            ,Price_ID
            ,Country
            ,Center 
            ,Amount  
            ,DR_CR 
            ,RANK() over (partition by ABS(Amount),DR_CR  order by CASE  WHEN DR_CR,Txn_ID ) RNK FROM Product),

select T1.*
from CTE t1
inner join CTE t2 on t1.abs(Amount)=t2.abs(Amount)
and t1.DR_CR<>t2.DR_CR
and t1.RNK=t2.RNK
```